# Typing $store property in Vue components

Tags: typescript, vue.js

[Here](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typing-store-property-in-vue-component) is a recipe on how to type `$store` property. But it doesn't work for me.

In vue 2 project created with vue-cliI, I added vuex.d.ts file to ./src but I `$store` property in my components still has type `Store<any>`

Content of vuex.d.ts file:

```
//imported from another file
interface State { 
  // ... type of my state
}

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {

  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: Store<State>
  }
}
```

Not sure what information you might need to determine why it's not working so please ask in the comments.

Comment: vuex.d.ts - you pasted a solution for Vue 3.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the vuex.d.ts file is the Vue 3 way of doig this.In Vue 2 there is no official way of adding types to Vuex, so I recommend using a 3rd party lib for this purpose.
Take a look at [Vuex Typex](https://github.com/mrcrowl/vuex-typex)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).